# Show that $\ell^2(A)$ and $\ell^2(B)$ are isomorphic iff $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $A,B$ be sets. Show that $\ell^2(A)$ and $\ell^2(B)$ are isomorphic iff $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality. (Here $\ell^2(A)$ is the square integrable functions that stand on $A$ with the counting measure)

The finite case is easy. If $A$ and $B$ are both infinite, the hint is to show that $B$ can be covered by a family of at most countable sets indexed by $A$, and vice versa. Then apply the Schroder-Bernstein theorem.

---

I want to know that how to show that $B$ can be covered by a family of at most countable sets indexed by $A$, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Is it possible for $A$ to have more than a countable number of points with nonzero measure?  Then, how many different infinite countable sets do you know?

Comment: Why not possible? What happen if $A = \mathbb R$ and the measure is counting measure?

Comment: @user112564:  Then every interval, I, has infinite measure, causing elements of $\ell^2(A)$ with support on $I$ to be contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an orthonormal basis on each of the two spaces. These have the same cardinality as $A$ and $B$, respectively. For example, if, for some $\alpha\in A$, $e_{\alpha}:A\to\mathbb C$ is defined as $e_{\alpha}(\alpha)=1$ and $e_{\alpha}(\alpha')=0$ for all $\alpha'\in A\setminus\{\alpha\}$, then $\{e_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is an orthonormal basis on $\ell^2(A)$. The construction of an orthonormal basis on $B$ is analogous. Then, the isomorphism defines another basis on $\ell^2(B)$, which has the same cardinality as $A$. The result follows from the fact that [two orthonormal bases on any Hilbert space have the same cardinality](http://planetmath.org/allorthonormalbaseshavethesamecardinality).